# Incorrect @onetomany annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am studying Hibernate and have faced with a non-clear situation, related to Hibernate annotations.

Let say we have two entities:

**Topic** and **Speaker**

One topic may relate to many speakers. One topic may have several speakers.
And one speaker may participate in several topics.

As it is shown below:

[image]

My plain application contains two entity classes: Topic class and Speaker class

And Topic class contains annotation, that declares one-to-many relationship with SPEAKERS via TOPIC_SPEAKERS table. TOPIC_SPEAKERS table is generated upon runtime if it does not exist.

*Topic.class (non-relevant code skipped)*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TOPICS")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long topicId;      

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "TOPIC_SPEAKERS",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "topicId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "speakerId")})
    private List<Speaker> speakersList;
```

*And Speaker class header:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SPEAKERS")
public class Speaker implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long speakerId;

    private String speakerName;
```

I have added two records to SPEAKERS table and it looks like that:

[image]

Then I added one topic to TOPICS table with reference to the first speaker (John Doe).

```
TOPICS table:
```

[image]

```
and TOPIC_SPEAKERS table:
```

[image]

All worked fine, until I tried to add another topic, that refers to the first speaker (John Doe). I.e add "Second topic" to TOPICS table and the reference of the "Second topic" in the "TOPIC_SPEAKERS" to the first speaker (John Doe).

Resulting TOPIC_SPEAKERS should be look like that (65536 - John Doe's id):

```
#     TOPICID     SPEAKERID
1      131072       65536
2      132111       65536
```

But Hibernate does not allow to insert a record to TOPIC_SPEAKERS with duplicate SPEAKERID value.

And I get the following error:

```
could not insert collection: [simpledbtest.model.Topic.speakersList#163840]
SEVERE: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value 
in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL130314230217010' 
defined on 'TOPIC_SPEAKERS'.

....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because 
it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique 
index identified by 'SQL130314230217010' defined on 'TOPIC_SPEAKERS'.

....

Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The statement was aborted because it 
would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index 
identified by 'SQL130314230217010' defined on 'TOPIC_SPEAKERS'.
```

**My question - how can I change annotation in Topic class to allow duplicate column values in generated TOPIC_SPEAKERS table?**

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the topic_speakers table in a one-to-many relationship? Normally in a one-to-may you would just create a foreign key topic_id in the speaker table. And just annotate the List<Speaker> with  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="topic_id")

Comment: One speaker may participate in several topics. And foreign key with speaker record won't be suitable in this case.

Comment: Which means the relationship is @ManyToMany and you should use the corresponding annotation right?

Comment: It is midnight here and I may miss something. But one topic -> many speakers, how can it be many to many relationship?

Comment: One topic -> many speakers, but in your earlier comment you said: "One speaker may participate in several topics. ..."

Comment: Yes, that is true. I also want to avoid speaker record duplication. And a speaker can be refered from many topics. Seems that there is one-to-many relationship annotation missing in Speaker class.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates use a set instead of a list and add a unique constraint on the join table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a ManyToMany relationship and have to use the @ManyToMany annotation. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TOPICS")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long topicId;      

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "TOPIC_SPEAKERS",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "topicId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "speakerId")})
    private Set<Speaker> speakersList;




@Entity
@Table(name="SPEAKERS")
public class Speaker implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long speakerId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "speakersList")
    private Set<Topic> topics;

    private String speakerName;
```